# How to manipulte / change array values loop retrieved from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, while-loop

I Select all from my table

```
  function convert(){

  $mysqli = new MySQLi('$server', '$database', '$password', '$username');   

  $Sql = "SELECT * FROM test1";
  $result = array();
  $res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $Sql);

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_BOTH)){
  $result[] = $row; 
  }
```

At this point I need to change array values and combine 2 columns. I'm able to make this work perfect on first set below Using KEY# rather than column name.

```
   for($i=0; $i< count ($result) ; $i++)
   if ($result[$i]['4'] == 'n'){
      $result[$i]['4'] = "ntu_";
    }
   else{
      $result[$i]['4'] =  "std_";
    }

  for($i=0; $i<count ($result) ; $i++)            
  if ($result[$i]['2'] == 'f'){
      $result[$i]['2'] = "female";
    }
  else{
      $result[$i]['2'] = "male";
    }

 for($i=0; $i<count ($result) ; $i++)
 if ($result[$i]['2'] == 'female' && $result[$i]['4'] == 'ntu_' ){
         $result[$i]['2'] = "ntu_female";
    }   
  elseif ($result[$i]['2'] == 'male' && $result[$i]['4'] == 'ntu_' ){
        $result[$i]['2'] = "ntu_male";
    }
  elseif ($result[$i]['2'] == 'female' && $result[$i]['4'] == 'std_' ){
        $result[$i]['2'] = "std_female";
    }
  elseif ($result[$i]['2'] == 'male' && $result[$i]['4'] == 'std_' ){
        $result[$i]['2'] = "std_male"; 
    }
```

THis second set IM NOT ABLE to make it work - same code as above though requires different Array KEYS - its for a different column. This is where the Method I'm using is not reliable. It does not combine the two values and if /else condition not converting properly. see print_r($array) below.

```
  for($i=0; $i< count ($result) ; $i++)
  if ($result[$i]['7'] == 'n'){
      $result[$i]['7'] = "ntu_";
    }
  else{
      $result[$i]['7'] =  "std_";
    }

 for($i=0; $i<count ($result) ; $i++)           
  if ($result[$i]['5'] == 'f'){
      $result[$i]['5'] = "female";
    }
  else {
      $result[$i]['5'] = "male";
    }

  for($i=0; $i<count ($result) ; $i++)
  if ($result[$i]['5'] == 'female' && $result[$i]['7'] == 'ntu_' ){
         $result[$i]['5'] = "ntu_female";
    }   
  elseif ($result[$i]['5'] == 'male' && $result[$i]['7'] == 'ntu_' ){
        $result[$i]['5'] = "ntu_male";
    }
  elseif ($result[$i]['5'] == 'female' && $result[$i]['7'] == 'std_' ){
        $result[$i]['5'] = "std_female";
    }
  elseif ($result[$i]['5'] == 'male' && $result[$i]['7'] == 'std_' ){
        $result[$i]['5'] = "std_male"; 
    }             

   //echo '<pre>';
  //print_r($result);
  //echo '</pre>';

  $_SESSION['Sql'] = $result;

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($_SESSION['Sql']);
  echo '</pre>';
```

Below is the Array values

```
  Array
  (
      [0] => Array
          (
              [0] => 1
              [id] => 1
              [1] => Kent Mercer
              [name] => Kent Mercer
              [2] => std_male
              [gender] => m
              [3] => 53
              [age] => 53
              [4] => std_
              [tobacco] => n
              [5] => std_male
              [s_gender] =>  f
              [6] => n
              [s_tobacco] => n
              [7] => std_
          )

      [1] => Array
          (
              [0] => 2
              [id] => 2
              [1] => Larry Bird
              [name] => Larry Bird
              [2] => std_male
              [gender] => m
              [3] => 42
              [age] => 42
              [4] => std_
              [tobacco] => y
              [5] => std_male
              [s_gender] => f
              [6] => n
              [s_tobacco] => n
              [7] => std_
        )

      [2] => Array
          (
              [0] => 3
              [id] => 3
              [1] => Linda Carter
              [name] => Linda Carter
              [2] => ntu_female
              [gender] => f
              [3] => 63
              [age] => 63
              [4] => ntu_
              [tobacco] => n
              [5] => std_male
              [s_gender] => m
              [6] => n
              [s_tobacco] => n
              [7] => std_
          )

   )
```

Below is DB table result - Notice that agender2 giving 1 value and incorrect - looks like it coping from agender but leaving off gender.

```
  id name             agender   age  agender2
  1 Kent Mercer     ntu_male    53  ntu_
  2 Larry Bird      std_male    42  std_
  3 Linda Carter    ntu_female  63  ntu_
```

All code below this line works perfect.

```
   if(!($stmt=$mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO `converted` (`id`,`name`,`agender`,`age`,`agender2`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)'))){      
   echo "<p>Prepare failed: ", mysqli_error($mysqli),"</p>";   
   }elseif(!$stmt->bind_param("issis",$id, $name, $gender, $age, $s_gender)){
   echo "<p>Binding failed: (",$stmt->errno,") ",$stmt->error,"</p>";     
   }else{    
  foreach($result as $i=>$row2){
  list($id,$name,$gender,$age,$s_gender)=$row2;  
  if(!$stmt->execute()){ // if the execute call fails
  echo "<p>Execute failed: (",$stmt->errno,") ",$stmt->error,"</p>";  
  }else{
  echo "<p>Success on index $i </p>";  
    }
    }
    }
    }

   ?>
```

Please Help. There has to be a better way to do this

This is Solution that got the job done; Thx to comment from @Used_By_Already
Basically using CASE expression to update columns in tables.

I would still like to know how I can change array element values and Insert into new TABLE, if anyone can lead me in right direction THX!!

```
   $gen = "UPDATE test1 SET gender = CASE 
   WHEN gender = 'f' THEN 'female'
   WHEN gender = 'm' THEN 'male'
           ELSE 'male'  
       END";
  if ($mysqli->query($gen) === TRUE) {
  echo "Record updated successfully";
  } else {
  echo "Error updating record: " . $mysqli->error;
  }

  $tob = "UPDATE test1 SET tobacco = CASE 
   WHEN tobacco = 'n' THEN 'ntu_'
   WHEN tobacco = 'y' THEN 'std_'
           ELSE 'std_'  
       END";     
  if ($mysqli->query($tob) === TRUE) {
  echo "Record updated successfully";
  } else {
echo "Error updating record: " . $mysqli->error;
 }                     

  $combine = "UPDATE test1 SET agender = CASE 
   WHEN tobacco = 'ntu_' AND gender = 'female' THEN 'ntu_female'
   WHEN tobacco = 'std_' AND gender = 'female' THEN 'std_female'
   WHEN tobacco = 'ntu_' AND gender = 'male' THEN 'ntu_male'
   WHEN tobacco = 'std_' AND gender = 'male' THEN 'std_male'
           ELSE 'std_male'  
       END";   
  if ($mysqli->query($combine) === TRUE) {
  echo "Record updated successfully";
  } else {
  echo "Error updating record: " . $mysqli->error;
 }
```

Comment: NEVER go into production using "select star", nominate the columns!!! Only then can you be certain of the column order. Also, just use a case expression in the sql to perform the concatenation.

Comment: why not use column names as keys of array?

Comment: @Used_By_Already thank you for your help. I added code for solution in above edit.  Could you elaborate on your remark "
NEVER go into production using "select star", nominate the columns".

Comment: "SELECT * FROM test1" should be "SELECT col1,col2,col3 ... col_n  FROM test1" i.e. SPECIFY the columns. You cannot guarantee that a default set of columns will always align to your assumptions of the array content in the php code, but if you specify the columns then you can rely on this.Take heed, "select *" can produce bugs

Comment: Got it! Thank you again.